# PySpark explode string of json

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There is a dataframe

```
data = [(42, """[{"param_a":9519,"param_b":7,"param_c":64},{"param_a":7483,"param_b":7,"param_c":1},{"param_a":1032,"param_b":7,"param_c":0}]""")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['key', 'value'])
```

Column `value` is of a String type, but it's valid json.
How to explode this column, so the output dataframe has 3 rows and next structure:

```
output_df: [(key, param_a, param_b, param_c)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the Json capabilities of Spark you can use the built-in function [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) to do the parsing of the `value` field and then [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) the result to split the result into single rows.

This approach is especially useful for a large amount of data that is too big to be processed on the Spark driver. A minor drawback is that you have to specify the Json schema explicitly.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

schema = "array<struct<param_a:long,param_b:long,param_c:long>>"

df.withColumn("parsed", F.from_json(F.col("value"),schema)) \
    .withColumn("exploded", F.explode("parsed")) \
    .select("key", "exploded.*")\
    .show()
```

prints

```
+---+-------+-------+-------+
|key|param_a|param_b|param_c|
+---+-------+-------+-------+
| 42|   9519|      7|     64|
| 42|   7483|      7|      1|
| 42|   1032|      7|      0|
+---+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Great. Thanks, but what to do when dataframe has several complex json formats? How to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You are having a json string in the "value" column. Try this.

```
import json

data = [(42,json.loads("""[{"param_a":9519,"param_b":7,"param_c":64},{"param_a":7483,"param_b":7,"param_c":1},{"param_a":1032,"param_b":7,"param_c":0}]""")) ]
hdr=['id','c1']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, hdr)
df.show(100,truncate=False)

+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |c1                                                                                                                                            |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|42 |[[param_a -> 9519, param_b -> 7, param_c -> 64], [param_a -> 7483, param_b -> 7, param_c -> 1], [param_a -> 1032, param_b -> 7, param_c -> 0]]|
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df.printSchema()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)

spark.sql("""
select id, explode(c1) c2 from df
""").show(100, truncate=False)

+---+----------------------------------------------+
|id |c2                                            |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|42 |[param_a -> 9519, param_b -> 7, param_c -> 64]|
|42 |[param_a -> 7483, param_b -> 7, param_c -> 1] |
|42 |[param_a -> 1032, param_b -> 7, param_c -> 0] |
+---+----------------------------------------------+

spark.sql("""
select id, c2["param_a"] param_a, c2["param_b"] param_b, c2["param_c"] param_c from (
select id, explode(c1) c2 from df )
""").show(100, truncate=False)

+---+-------+-------+-------+
|id |param_a|param_b|param_c|
+---+-------+-------+-------+
|42 |9519   |7      |64     |
|42 |7483   |7      |1      |
|42 |1032   |7      |0      |
+---+-------+-------+-------+
```